# Why does this Trigger not fire?

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Image Source="Data\Images\close_nohover.bmp">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Data\Images\close_hover.bmp" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the trigger changes the Source Property, the Source must be set within the Style and not explicitly on the Image. Like this

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Data\Images\close_nohover.bmp"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Data\Images\close_hover.bmp" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: I'll take this opportunity to learn a little bit about WPF. Does this mean that properties set on the element *always* take precedence over anything declared in a style, even when the property set in the style would be "more recent" (ie. set last)?

Comment: Yes, even if you start out with the above example and then set the Source in code behind or something then the trigger will stop working. Properties set on the element always has precedence over Properties set in Style. Example, I think it would be confusing if you have a Style for a Rectangle with a default Fill of Green, and then you set Fill="Red" on the Rectangle and it stays Green because of the Style:)

Comment: Add: If you clear the value for source with image.ClearValue(Image.SourceProperty) then the Trigger will start to work again.